# Jquery .text() stripping html not working in IE-8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function datacheck(content){
var content = "<script>for(var i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) alert('hello')</script>";
 var text = $(content).text();

alert(text);

}
</script>
<body>
<div>
Click  <input type="button" name="button1" onclick="datacheck()" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

$(content).text(); is working in all browsers striping out html content but not working in IE-8 , if I use

```
 var content = "<p>for(var i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) alert('hello')</p>";
```

then it is working fine in IE-8 too.
Can anyone help me how can I make **$(content).text();**  working in IE8 too.
Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the browser is seeing the `<script>` tags in the string and deciding that this means the end of the script.

Lesson 1: Never include a `<script>` tag inside your javascript code, even if it's within a string. There is a chance that browsers might mis-interpret it.

Ways around it:

- Include comments or CDATA tags around your script code. eg

  ```
  <script>
  <!--
  ...... js code here ........
  -->
  </script>
  ```
- Break the `<script>` tags in your string up into substrings. eg

  ```
  var content = "<sc"+"ript>for(var i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) alert('hello')</scr"+"ipt>";
  ```
- Just don't use `<script>` tags in this way -- if you're using it to inject JS code into your page, there are almost certainly better ways of doing so. Perhaps you should use a library like [require.js](http://www.requirejs.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a [CDATA tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
function datacheck(content){
var content = "<script>for(var i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) alert('hello')</script>";
 var text = $(content).text();

alert(text);

}
]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Right didn't test it sorry. It works with Spudleys suggestion of comments. But the best would be to redesign it in another way.

Comment: yes...redesigned it <script>

function datacheck(content){
var content = "<script>for(var i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) alert('hello')</script>"; content = '<![CDATA[' + content + ']]>';
 var text = $(content).text();

alert(text);

}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function datacheck(content){
var content = "<script>for(var i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) alert('hello')</script>";
content = '<![CDATA[' + content + ']]>';
 var text = ($(content).text()).replace(']]>', '');
alert(text);
}
</script>
```

This will work correctly. 
Thanks tea2code for your answer.